# Calculating average of range of values in a column dynamically - excel

Tags: javascript, python, excel

I have many sheets in 1 excel.

Sheet 1: 
One of the columns in sheet1 looks like this

```
separator
14124
25362
32
32387
23
23
separator
25
3263
33
2
separator
25326
323
separator
623
2362
233
88
separator
236523
32
23
2323
232
23
23
223
2
```

Basically, a range of values are separated by  "separator". I want to take the average of the values between two "separator" and print it out in a separate row in sheet2. 
I can surely do that manually by highlighting the range of values, but I don't want to do it manually. The range of the values & the location can vary. 
Is there any way to write a formula to detect the word "separator" & sum up all the range of values between two separator dynamically without selecting the cell range and print them in another row in another sheet?

I can surely write a program in Java because thats what I know. But do we need python or javascript here for this manipulation? Have never used excel manipulation using python etc. Or can we do it in excel? If we need python or js, Can someone give me a rough idea as to how to do this?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

For the reading, you can use the pandas library and its read_excel function:
see [pandas documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13.1/generated/pandas.io.excel.read_excel.html).

Note that you will need to install the xlrd package from pip

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.read_excel(filename, "Sheet1",header=None,skiprows=0)
```

where filename is you excel filename and "Sheet1" is the name of the first sheet in your excel document (it must be a valid sheet name).

Somehow I had to use header=0 but may depends on you version of the excel file. So, let us assume that the resulting output (df), looks like

```
        0
0   separator
1  25362
2  32
3  32387
4  23
5  23
6 separator
7   25
8   3263
...
```

Now, for splitting according to the separator name and saving into a new sheet, it would require more thinking and coding...

One way to identify where is the separator is to use:

```
df == "separator"
```

Hoping this is a good starting point.

Comment: oh great. thanks :) . (I use Macbook) Do you recommend me any specific Python IDE? I've never used python before.

Comment: and one more question. df = pd.read_excel(filename, sheetname) will give me the whole data in excel file. How do I locate just a specific column? And whats the way to access it? Is the data stored as an array or something?

Comment: if you have a column name, type df[column_name] to access to one column or to access to the column 1 (0 in python), type df[0]

Comment: ok I'll do that. but whenever I store the data, what is it stored as? A string , an array  ? Thanks :)

Comment: yes this should surely be a good starting point. Thanks a ton :)